Adding an SNS destination to a lambda using SAM
I'm working on a project where I need to use SNS to send emails indicating a success/failure when a lambda completes. I have managed to find examples detailing individual pieces of the puzzle (see: https://serverlessland.com/patterns/lambda-sns and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-onsuccess.html) but i can't seem to find anything to tie it all together. What do I need to do to configure a template.yaml that will create a destination, attach it to the lambda, and point it at the SNS topic?
For reference my current template looks like:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  Lambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: my.func.Lambda
      Runtime: java11
      CodeUri: ${lambda.functionCode}
      FunctionName: ${aws.prefix}_${environment}_${functionalArea}_${integrationId}
      EventInvokeConfig:
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 2
        DestinationConfig:
          OnFailure:
            Type: SNS
            Destination: !Ref SnsTopic
          OnSuccess:
            Type: SNS
            Destination: !Ref SnsTopic     
  SnsTopic:
      Type: 'AWS::SNS::Topic'
      Properties:
        TopicName: result-topic
  SNSSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: me@mail.com
      Protocol: email
      TopicArn: !Ref SnsTopic

When I deploy this project I end up with a lambda with no destination configured. Any help on troubleshooting this would be appreciated

When run sam deploy with your template, I get a Lambda function that has a destination of the SNS topic.

It can be an issue on the stack. Please try to delete the stack and re-deploy this template.
